# VirtualBox stuck on Windows Logo

Tags: virtualbox, linux-mint

I recently migrated to Linux Mint and I am trying to install Windows 10 but the VirtualBox is stuck on the Windows logo. I downloaded the ISO from Microsoft. I have allotted 3.5 GB RAM to the VM.

Comment: Do you set all the required settings properly for Windows VM? Does guest VM show any error with that Windows logo?

Comment: Do you have UEFI enabled? I had to enable it to get Win 10 to work. Also oddly enough I had to disable secure boot on the host machine.

Comment: I have the Secure Boot disabled. How can I confirm that UEFI is enabled?

Comment: @Biswa: I kept the Virtualbox settings as defaults and only changed the "Empty" value in "Storage" to the iso I downloaded.

Comment: VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --firmware efi should do the trick.

Comment: @EddieDunn: I checked my BIOS settings, Boot List Option has "UEFI" as the selected option. Does UEFI Network Stack needs to be enabled as well?

Comment: UEFI Network stack does not matter. So you have an efi firmware loaded? IE you are asked to hit a key to boot from cd/dvd?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58730/discussion-between-harmeet-and-eddie-dunn).

Comment: I downloaded another ISO and it worked.

Answer (score 26):

Try disabling paravirtualization:

Settings -> System -> Acceleration -> Paravirtualization Interface: None

I was able to start installation of Windows 10 (64bit) on VirtualBox 5.0 Ubuntu by disabling this feature.

Comment: This worked, I wonder why.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you... using OSX 10.11.6 and VirtualBox 5.0.14

Comment: Broke mine, but selecting KVM works

Comment: Didn't work, but disabling the USB Controller did.

Answer (score 5):

I removed VirtualBox 5.0 and installed the Oracle VirtualBox 5.1 and it went through. No other options helped.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem, and changing paravirtualisation did not help.
I had also installed the virtualbox-ext-pack package (Ubuntu host) and enabled USB3.

Unchecking the following allowed me to install:
Settings > USB > Enable USB Controller

Comment: Amazingly this worked! (After trying so many virtualization options configurations...) Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me as well. Win10 1909, VirtualBox 5.1.18

Answer (score 0):

*The original post is about Linux Mint, but seeing how the other 3 threads link here and this being the first hit on Google when searching for this specific problem I'll leave my comment here*

I was trying to create a Win10 VM on a Win10 machine, but I was getting stuck on the install. Tried all of the above, but to no avail. The problem turned out to be that **Intel Virtualization** wasn't enabled in BIOS. After that I could enable VT-x/AMD-V ( Settings > System > Acceleration ). Not sure if you need Hyper-V disabled, mine was already turned off.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this question as I just did... I tried this on three different mint installs, thinking if I could get it to work on one, I could just transport the finished VM. NONE of the three worked. So I worked my way thorugh proposed solutions until removal of USB worked. So I got curious and just tried a different USB controller, set it to 2.0 and it worked as well, tried it on the other systems and same results on all three. USB3 was default, I guess this happens when you install the extension pack? So consistently I did not have to remove USB, I just set it to USB 2.0.

Installing w10/1909 on mint 18.3 and 19.3, virtualbox 5.1.38_Ubuntu r122592

---

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was stuck during install. I just needed to enable EFI in

```
Settings > System > Enable EFI (special OSes only)
```

Not sure if it's the right way to proceed (especially due to the note about "special OSes"), but seems to work so far (you just need to press a key to boot on the installation media at boot time the first time).

Answer (score -2):

I fixed the issue by increasing the number of CPUs from 1 to 4. This might seem obvious but I forgot to check this setting and somehow this was the default for a new VM in VirtualBox.